# Blender 3 stroke tweening?

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d, interpolation

I'm returning to Blender after its update from 2.9 to 3. I'm a 2D animator and was very impressed by Blender 2.9's interpolation mechanics - especially it being able to edit strokes down to the vertex and tween the changes. However, I'm at a loss to find that function again. Every tutorial and document I've found that even mentions tweening stroke edits is from 2.9.

Am I missing something or does Blender 3 just not have this feature?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the feature you're talking about being used in the interface of the software ?

Answer (score 1):

I reckon you mean Interpolation, which you can find as an *Active Tool* in the viewport's toolbar (which you can toggle using <kbd>T</kbd>):

[image: active tool]

You can also find it as an operator using <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> while your cursor is in the viewport.

Source:
[Interpolation — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/animation/interpolation.html)